# Jqgrid + JQuery Autocomplete multiple input

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid, autocomplete

I have the grid set up and working nicely. I wanted to add multiple input autocomplete functionality to the form view in JqGrid. The multiple autocomplete works but the extractLast function seems not to be working and I can add duplicate inputs. 
Heres the code:

```
var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
function split( val ) {
        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
        }
        function extractLast( term ) {
            return split( term ).pop();
        }
        function autocomplete_element(value, options) {
          // creating input element
          var $ac = $('<input type="text"/>');
          // setting value to the one passed from jqGrid
          $ac.val(value);
          // creating autocomplete
          $ac.autocomplete(
                {source: function( request, response ) {
                // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                    availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
            },

                focus: function() {
                    // prevent value inserted on focus
                    return false;
                },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    var terms = split( this.value );
                    // remove the current input
                    terms.pop();
                    // add the selected item
                    terms.push( ui.item.value );
                    // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                    terms.push( "" );
                    this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                    return false;
                }
            });
          // returning element back to jqGrid
          return $ac;
        }
        function autocomplete_value(elem, op, value) {
          if (op == "set") {
            $(elem).val(value);
          }
          return $(elem).val();
        }
```

Grid colmodel:

```
{
                ...
                editable: true,
                edittype: "custom",
                editoptions: {
                    custom_element: autocomplete_element,
                    custom_value: autocomplete_value
                }
            },
```

Which I found from [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple)

and [German Rumm's blog](http://germanrumm.eu/adding-jqueryui-autocomplete-to-jqgrid-edit-form/)

Any suggestions?

**UPDATED!**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like example on jQuery UI site allows selecting the same element multiple times as well. The problem is in `source` function - it always checks the last term against all available terms when creating a suggest list.

Modify `select` callback to display only those terms that are not already present in a field.

```
source: function(request, response) {
  var terms = request.terms.split(/,\s*/);
  var last_term = terms.pop();

  var tags = $.grep(availableTags, function(el) {
    return $.inArray(el, terms) == -1);
  });

  response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(tags, last_term))
}
```